# JSoup Retrieve URL Not Working

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a [URL](http://www.baidu.com/link?url=7ygPGJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhhwH3nAI9fF7k3rpEUPN38B5JxSjcxggx52Vzl-7OHM6803JG7iS5jWXVV2MXlPFedN-RZl6Mui_vhsT5c) and I use JSoup to retieve web page indicated by this url.

```
try{
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:48)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:24)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:59)
```

Comment: the usl is http://www.baidu.com/link?url=7ygPGJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhhwH3nAI9fF7k3rpEUPN38B5JxSjcxggx52Vzl-7OHM6803JG7iS5jWXVV2MXlPFedN-RZl6Mui_vhsT5c

Comment: Perhaps add more code. Where is `url` declared? Where is it initialised?

Comment: url may be passed null or empty.. better check it with `StringUtils.isBlank()` before passing to jsoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following:

1. You are passing intended URL to `url` variable.
2. The URL is well formed just to be doubly sure.

The Method `notEmpty` in Validate.java of Jsoup checks if the Url is not empty.

```
    public static void notEmpty(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String must not be empty");
    }
```

Comment: The url variable is of type String.

Comment: Yeah, `url` variable means the name of the variable is url. What is the value that is being passed?

Comment: Something like http://www.baidu.com/link?url=o7NTGJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhgtiedK6BcCm1YgkoSNxufKUd8FDN7rcojR78x-m3F

Comment: the url automatically encoded by the system.