# HTML parsing Android Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

im kinda new to android, im trying to use jsoup to parse a html page to gather some info from a page.
i would like to insert a url via pop-up (altertbox) usinga method called loadwebsite:

```
private void loadWebsite(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Inserisci url sito");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            linkurl = input.getText().toString();
            //linkurl="https://"+linkurl;
            url123.setText("https://"+linkurl.toString());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();



}
```

and a method called getsiteinfo()

```
private void getinfoWebsite(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                Document  doc = Jsoup.connect(linkurl).get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Element image = doc.select("img").first();
                String imgSrc = image.absUrl("src");
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                builder.append(title).append("\n");
            } catch (IOException e){
             builder.append("Error :").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}
```

the problem is that when i try to pass a url via textbox i get that error:

```
03-26 17:22:16.826 26651-26840/it.uninsubria.pdm.htmlparsingjsoup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
                                                                                Process: it.uninsubria.pdm.htmlparsingjsoup, PID: 26651
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
                                                                                    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
                                                                                    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:72)
                                                                                    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:36)
                                                                                    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
                                                                                    at it.uninsubria.pdm.htmlparsingjsoup.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

here is the full code:

`import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button getBtn;
    private TextView result;
    private ImageView img;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Button button2;
    private String linkurl = "";
    private TextView url123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        url123 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.url123);

        getBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);              //
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    // Pulsante "open website
            @Override                                             //
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openWebsite();

            }

        });
        getBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadWebsite();
                getinfoWebsite();
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        });
    }




    //////////////////////////////////////////// -------------------METHODS------------------////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void getinfoWebsite(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    Document  doc = Jsoup.connect(linkurl).get();
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Element image = doc.select("img").first();
                    String imgSrc = image.absUrl("src");
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    builder.append(title).append("\n");
                } catch (IOException e){
                 builder.append("Error :").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void openWebsite(){
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(linkurl));
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //pop-up text per caricare link url
    private void loadWebsite(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Inserisci url sito");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                linkurl = input.getText().toString();
                //linkurl="https://"+linkurl;
                url123.setText("https://"+linkurl.toString());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();



    }
}`

Comment: have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097275/jsoup-retrieve-url-not-working

Comment: I get the error even before i could insert the url

Comment: Why do you assign values twice to the same variable - `getBtn`?

Comment: The error says that the argument you are passing to Jsoup.connect is not valid (empty). It looks like you creating onClick listener to set value of `linkurl`, but you are starting parsing thread immediately, i.e. not waiting for linkurl value to be set.  You can for example delay execution of the code by inserting this code in the begining of run method inside getinfoWebsite(): `while(linkurl.isEmpty()) {  Thread.sleep(1000);}`

Comment: Thanks @Luk it fixxed my problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the argument you are passing to Jsoup.connect is not valid (empty). It looks like you creating onClick listener to set value of `linkurl`, but you are starting parsing thread immediately, i.e. not waiting for `linkurl` value to be set. You can for example delay execution of the code by inserting this code in the begining of run method inside getinfoWebsite(): `while(linkurl.isEmpty()) { Thread.sleep(1000);}`